# What do you write in conditionals when there are doubles

Tags: java, android

When i use || in if statements android studio tells me "Operator || cannot be aplied to 'int', 'double' " 
So what's the problem? Please help 
Don't be mad if code is bad i'm new to programming.
This was written in Android studio

```
package com.ftech.kalkulatorzamalumaturu;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Kalkulator extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kalkulator);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}

public void onOcistiClick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e3);
    EditText e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e4);
    EditText e5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e5);
    EditText e6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e6);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
    TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pt);
    e1.setText("");
    e2.setText("");
    e3.setText("");
    e4.setText("");
    e5.setText("");
    e6.setText("");
    t1.setText("");
    t2.setText("");
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e3);
    EditText e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e4);
    EditText e5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e5);
    EditText e6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.e6);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
    TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pt);
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(e3.getText().toString());
    double num4 = Double.parseDouble(e4.getText().toString());
    double num5 = Double.parseDouble(e5.getText().toString());
    double num6 = Double.parseDouble(e6.getText().toString());


    if ( num1 = 0 || num2 = 0) {
        t2.setText("Popuni neko polje!");
    }else {

        double sum = (num1*4) + (num2*5) + (num3*5) + num4 + num5 + num6;
        t2.setText("Broj bodova od skole je:");
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it's the same, `||`

Comment: It shows me error in android studio

Comment: what error does it show??

Comment: "For string you use `||`". That pretty much wrong. Have you tried using the `||`-operator on two strings? You're using the `||` operator on two bools!

Comment: Maybe we need to clarify what || means.  It doesn't mean that thing you use when you want "more variables."  It means that you want the whole expression to return true if one of the two conditions returns true.  Since the || operator needs a boolean, it doesn't matter what types you're using to start off so long as they return boolean type.

Comment: Are you sure that your values are _exactly_ 0? Not some value that's very, very close to 0? Standard practice with doubles is to not compare them to an exact value, but to see if they're close-enough (ie, take the absolute value of `actual - expected` and compare it to some sufficiently small epsilon). Doubles have rounding behavior that can be quite surprising if you're not expecting it.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud. So your original question, with `==`, wasn't a remotely accurate reflection of your actual code, which uses `=` instead. ***Programming is a detail-oriented pursuit***. Please take the time with your next question to ensure that you're actually asking about the thing you're having trouble with.

Comment: And in particular, especially for a problem as self-contained as this, please try to create a short, complete program that can demonstrate the problem. In his case, that program would have been about 9 lines, including boilerplate stuff. This has two advantages: firstly, it helps us answer the question, confident that we're answering the right thing (since we can all agree on the exact code that shows the problem); and perhaps more importantly, in creating that program you may have found the problem yourself ("oh, my original uses `=` but this version uses `==` and works."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing with

```
if ( num1 = 0 || num2 = 0)
```

when it should be

```
if ( num1 == 0 || num2 == 0)
```

One `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 5):

You need to compare it the same way, but with `double` values. Instead of using 0 (`int`) use 0.0 (`double`):

```
if ( n == 0.0 || c== 0.0 ){
   System.out.println("What do i write instead of \"?\" ");
}
```

Comment: An int `0` would work just fine, too -- it'll get promoted to `double` automatically.

Comment: @F.Pajic: "Not working" doesn't help anyone work out what's wrong. The code in Andrew's answer shoudl be fine if `n` and `c` are `double` variables.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that comparing equality with doubles is a generally bad idea.  You should only compare with operators <=, <, >, >=.

Comment: @F.Pajic are you sure the error is at the head of the if-statement and not inside the body of the if-statement (which had several syntactical errors)

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator only operates on *booleans* in Java. In your string example, you're not using it with *strings*, you're using it with booleans, because `equals` returns a `boolean`:

```
if( n.equals("") || c.equals("") ){
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^----^^^^^^^^^^^^------- booleans
   System.out.println(/*...*/);
}
```

So what you need to do is use something that gives you a boolean. Your `==` will, for instance:

```
if ( n == 0 || c== 0 ){
//   ^^^^^^----^^^^^------- booleans
   System.out.println(/*...*/);
}
```

What you *can't* do is expect it to convert doubles to booleans:

```
double d1 = 1.0;
double d2 = 0.0;
if (d1 || d2) {
//  ^^^^^^^^------- WON'T WORK, doubles are not booleans
}
```

Some languages would coerce those values to booleans. Java will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double i = 1.5;
    double j = 3.4;
    if((i==4.3) || (j==2.1)){
        //to do code here
    }
```

I don't have any error.

Comment: Note that you don't need those extra brackets - `if (i == 4.3 || j == 2.1)` would be fine too.